# Lots of NaN and incorrect values in a block of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not excellent with javascript as you will see by the code (http://jsfiddle.net/au59P/2/). I've got my calculations partially working, but with a lot of incorrect results. I've spent all night working on it so I need some pointers to see where I'm going wrong.

Here's the HTML:

```
<table cell-spacing="0" cell-padding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Int</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>
                <input />
            </td>
            <td>30.00</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Int</td>
            <td>50.00</td>
            <td>
                <input />
            </td>
            <td>30.00</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Int</td>
            <td>60.00</td>
            <td>
                <input />
            </td>
            <td>30.00</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td>Subtotal</td>
            <td class="subtotal"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Int</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>
                <input />
            </td>
            <td>40.50</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Int></td>
            <td>50.00</td>
            <td>
                <input />
            </td>
            <td>45.50</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Int</td>
            <td>60.00</td>
            <td>
                <input />
            </td>
            <td>50.50</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td>Subtotal</td>
            <td class="subtotal"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Int</td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td>
                <input />
            </td>
            <td>30.00</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Int></td>
            <td>50.00</td>
            <td>
                <input />
            </td>
            <td>40.00</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Int</td>
            <td>60.00</td>
            <td>
                <input />
            </td>
            <td>50.50</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td>Subtotal</td>
            <td class="subtotal"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="active">Active</td>
        <td class="total"></td>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the js:

```
var sumVal = 0;
function currentSum(){
    $(".subtotal").each(function(){
        sumVal += parseFloat($(this).text()).toFixed(2);
    });
};
$("input").keyup(function(){
    var newRate = parseFloat($(this).val(), 10).toFixed(2);
    var multiplier = parseFloat($(this).parent().next("td").text(), 10).toFixed(2);
    var calcRate = parseFloat(newRate * multiplier).toFixed(2);
    $(this).parent().next("td").next("td").text("$" + calcRate).addClass("calculated");

    var $tr = $(this).closest("tbody").find("tr");
    var $total = $tr.has("td[colspan]");
    var subCalc = 0;
    $tr.not($total).each(function(){
        if($(this).find(".calculated").text() !== ""){
            var tempCalc = parseFloat($(".calculated").text().replace("$",""),10).toFixed(2);
            subCalc += +parseFloat(tempCalc).toFixed(2);
        };
    });
    $total.find("td.subtotal").text("$" + subCalc);
    currentSum();
    $(".active").next(".total").text(sumVal);
});
```

When entering a value in the input, it updates the multiplier in the 5th td, however the subtotal calculation is wrong, and the total calculation returns NaN. What's more, when I delete the value in one of the inputs, everything turns to NaN where I thought I had that if conditional in there to ignore all NaN.

Comment: `parseFloat()` only takes one argument. In this script you're giving it two in two places (I think you're thinking of parseInt). This won't make it work, though.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: @doctororange: I believe the second argument is just ignored in this case.

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), set break points, inspect variables and then you will find out at which point the value becomes `NaN` and then you can investigate more on that specific operation.

Comment: I think so too, @FelixKling, but it's worth noting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few problems

```
function currentSum() {
    var sumVal = 0;
    $(".subtotal").each(function () {
        sumVal += parseFloat($(this).text().replace('$', '')) || 0;
    });
    return sumVal.toFixed(2);
};
```

then

```
$(".active").next(".total").text('$' + currentSum());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yYP2a/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that `parseFloat` returns you a correct number before using it:

```
var someVar = /* parseFloat ... */
if (!isNaN(someVar)) {
    // use someVar
}
```

Your main problem being `parseFloat("$10")` gives `NaN` because of the `$`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/au59P/3/) (there are still some issues with computations)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sumVal = 0;
var subCalc = 0;
function currentSum(){
$(".calculated").each(function(){
    sumVal = (parseFloat(sumVal)+parseFloat($(".calculated").text().replace("$",""),10)).toFixed(2);
});
};
$("input").keyup(function(){
var newRate = parseFloat($(this).val(), 10).toFixed(2);
var multiplier = parseFloat($(this).parent().next("td").text(), 10).toFixed(2);
var calcRate = parseFloat(newRate * multiplier).toFixed(2);
$(this).parent().next("td").next("td").text("$" + calcRate).addClass("calculated");

var $tr = $(this).closest("tbody").find("tr");
var $total = $tr.has("td[colspan]");

$tr.not($total).each(function(){
    if($(this).find(".calculated").text() !== ""){
        var tempCalc = parseFloat($(".calculated").text().replace("$",""),10).toFixed(2);
        subCalc = parseFloat(parseFloat(subCalc)+parseFloat(tempCalc)).toFixed(2);
    };
});
$total.find("td.subtotal").text("$" + subCalc);
currentSum();
$(".active").next(".total").text(sumVal);
});
```

I made some changes to your script. It solves some problem. You can proceed from there.

Comment: The problem u got is due to "toFixed" function it returns String. That causes trouble for you.